# Multiple dependent dynamic drop down list in jsp,servlet and Mysql.

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

category table which have attributes id(pk) and cat_name

category table

id   cat_name

1   arts

2   technology

subcategory table which have attributes s_id(pk) name and id(fk)

subcategory table

s_id  name       id

1     astrology  1

2     mobile     2

this is Submit_story.jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*"  %>
<%@page import="com.blog.ConnectionManager"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<%@page import="com.blog.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%
   List<category_Bean> category = new DAO().getcategory() ;
          request.setAttribute("category",category);
 %>

<!--  String cat=null; -->


<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script_reg.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title align=center > Submit Story </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<%

       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blogspot","root","mysql");

 %>
     <% 
            String sql3 = "select * from author";
            Statement stmt3 = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery(sql3);


     %>



<div id="container">
    <div id="header"><h1><i>Blogspot.in</i></h1>
    </div> 

    <div id="body_contant_admin">
    <div id="hello">
    </div>
        <div id="form_container_reg">
        <fieldset>
        <legend> <b> SUBMIT STORY </b> </legend>
        <form name="input" action="submit_story" method="post">
        <div style="color: #000F1F;">${msg}</div>
        <div id="author_reg">

        <table>


        <tr>
        <td class="td1" class="text_entry"><b>Category:</b></td>
        <td class="td1" class="text_entry"> 
        <select name="category" id ="category_id" onchange="callajax()" >
        <option value="0">Select</option>
           <c:forEach  var="category" items="${category}">
           <option value="${category.id}">${category.cat_name}</option>
           </c:forEach>    
        </select>

        <%   

        %>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td class="td1" class="text_entry"><b> Subcategory: </b></td>
        <td class="td1" class="text_entry">

         <select name="subcategory" id="subcategoryId">
          <option value='0'>--Select--</option>
         </select>

        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td class="td1" class="text_entry"><b>Author Name:</b> </td> 
        <td class="td1" class="text_entry"> 
            <select name="name">
        <option selected="selected"> Select Author Name </option>
        <%  while(rs3.next()){ %>

            <option><%= rs3.getString(3)%></option>
            <!--  String cat = request.getString("category"); -->
        <% } %>
        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td class="td1"><b>Title:</b></td>
        <td class="td1"><input type="text" name="title" placeholder="enter first Name " class="text_entry"></td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
        <td class="td1" class="text_entry"><b>Description:</b> </td> 
        <td class="td1"> <textarea style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" name="description" placeholder="Write your story here" class="text_entry"></textarea></td>

        </tr>




        </table>

        </div>

        <br>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="reg_validateForm()" align="middle"/>
        &nbsp &nbsp  <input type="reset" value="Reset" align="middle"/><br><br>
        <!--  
        <a href="author_home.jsp" title="admin home" >
        <input type="button" name="myaccount"  value="Admin home">
        </a>  
        -->
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="button" value="Author home" onclick="fun1()"/>
        </form>
        </fieldset>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    <div id="menu">

        <table >
        <tr>
          <td> <a href="home.jsp" title="Home" >Home</a> </td>

          <td> <a href="category.jsp" title="Category" >Category</a> </td>

          <td> <a href="subcategory.jsp" title="Subcategory" >Subcategory</a> </td>

          <td> <a href="aboutus.jsp" title="aboutus" >About us</a> </td>

          <td> <a href="contactus.jsp" title="Countactus" >Contact us</a> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
       <div id="copyright">&copy;copyright Jk Technosoft Ltd. ALL Rights Reserved.
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fun1()
{
    location.href="author_home.jsp";
}

function getXMLHttpRequestObject()
{ 
var xmlhttp;
    try 
    {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) 
      {
        try 
      {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (E) 
        {
          xmlhttp = false;
        }
      }
  if (!xmlhttp)
    {
    try 
      {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } 
       catch (e) 
        {
         xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
   return xmlhttp;
}
function callajax()
{

var http = new getXMLHttpRequestObject();
var url="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>/subcategory_ajax.jsp?categoryId="+document.getElementById('category_id').value;
http.open("GET", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.timeout=1000;
http.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
          if(http.readyState == 4) 
          {
            if(http.status==200)
          {
            document.getElementById("subcategoryId").innerHTML=http.responseText;
          }
         }
}
http.send(null);
}

</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

This is category_Bean.java

```
package com.blog;

import java.io.Serializable;
public class category_Bean {

           public int id;
           public String cat_name;


        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getCat_name() {
            return cat_name;
        }
        public void setCat_name(String cat_name) {
            this.cat_name = cat_name;
        }
}
```

this is DBUtil.java

```
package com.blog;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class DBUtil {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection con=null;
        try{

            if(con== null) {
                javax.naming.Context context = new InitialContext();
                if(context == null )
                   throw new Exception("Boom - No Context");
                DataSource dataSource =(DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/msplash");

                  if (dataSource != null)
                    con = dataSource.getConnection();

            }
            return con;
        } catch(SQLException e){
            throw new SQLException(e.toString());
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new SQLException(e.toString());
        }
    }

            public static void closeResource(Connection con,PreparedStatement pst,ResultSet rst){
       if (rst != null)
                        try {
                                    rst.close();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                        }


       if (pst != null) {
               try {
                        pst.close();
               } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
               }
       }
       if (con != null) {
               try {
                        con.close();
               } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
               }
       }

     }


}
```

this is subcategory_ajax.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="com.blog.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@page import="com.*"%>
<%=new DAO().getsubcategory(request.getParameter("categoryId"))%> 
</body>
</html>
```

this is DAO.java

```
package com.blog;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
public class DAO {

           public List<category_Bean> getcategory() {

                    Connection connection = null;
                    PreparedStatement statement=null;
                    ResultSet resultSet=null;
                    List<category_Bean> category = new ArrayList<category_Bean>();
                     try {
                             connection = DBUtil.getConnection();
                             if(connection!=null)
                             {
                                      statement = connection.prepareStatement("select *from category");
                                      resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
                                       while(resultSet.next()) 
                                       {
                                         category_Bean cat = new category_Bean();
                                         cat.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                                         cat.setCat_name(resultSet.getString("cat_name"));
                                         category.add(cat);
                                       }

                               }



                   }catch (Exception e) {
                           category=null;
                   }finally{
                             DBUtil.closeResource(connection, null, resultSet);
                   }
                   return category;
          }



public String getsubcategory(String categoryId){

                 StringBuffer buf=new StringBuffer();
                 Connection con=null;
                 ResultSet resultSet=null;
                 PreparedStatement pst=null;
                 try{
                     con=DBUtil.getConnection();
                     if(con!=null){

                         String query="select s_id,name from subcategory where id='"+categoryId+"'";
                         pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
                         resultSet=pst.executeQuery();
                         while(resultSet.next()){
                                buf.append("<option value='"+resultSet.getInt("id")+"'>");
                                buf.append(resultSet.getString("name")+"</option>");
                         }
                     }

                 }catch(Exception ex){
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                 }finally{
                       DBUtil.closeResource(con, null, resultSet);
                 }
                 return buf.toString();
             }

}
```

The Error is that does not show any category or subcategory in drop down list.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `alert(http.responseText);` to see what the Ajax is actually returning?

Answer (score 0):

You have this HTML:

```
    <select name="subcategory" id="subcategoryId">
      <option value='0'>--Select--</option>
     </select>
```

You call Ajax to populate it, finally doing `document.getElementById("subcategoryId").innerHTML=http.responseText;`.

Now the JSP file that your Ajax is sending the request to returns a full HTML file.  That is, it has a `<!DOCTYPE` and `<html>` and `<body>` and so on.

Why???   What kind of HTML goes inside a `<select>` tag's innerHTML?  A list of options, not a full HTML file.

So, shouldn't your JSP that's being called by the Ajax only return a list of options?

```
 <option value='0'>--Select--</option>
 <option value='1'>1</option>
 <option value='2'>2</option>
```